# Self-Learning XCode/Objective-C: 'static' doesn't seem to mean what I *think* it means

Tags: objective-c

I'm working through examples in the book 'Visual Quick Start, Objective-C' by Holzner. I spend a lot of time with each example, getting the code debugged is the faster part, and then stepping through saying to myself why each line of code works, what each word in each line does and  deciding why the author used one way of doing things versus another. Then I repeat the example with some story of my own. This seems to be a good way to move from being a structured programmer and to an oop-like one. It works with these examples because he just does one concept at a time. (I've worked part way through 2 other books and this idea did not work for me in those. Once I got confused by something, I just stayed confused. There were too many variables in the lengthier, more complex examples.)

In the current example (page 137), Holzner uses the word 'static'. I looked through examples in this book to decide what this word means. I also read the description in Bjarne Stroustrups' C++ Programming Language  book (I understand that C++ and Objective-C are not exactly the same)

(Bjarne Stroustup p 145) 
use a static variable as a memory, 
   instead of a global variable that 'might be accessed and corrupted by other functions'

Here is what I understand 'static' means as a result. I thought that meant that the value of a static variable would never change. I thought that meant it was like a constant value, that once you set it to 1 or 5 it couldn't be changed during that run.

But in this example piece of code, the value of the static variable *does* change. So I am really unclear on what 'static' means.

(Please ignore the 'followup question' I left commented in. I didn't want to change anything from my run, and risk creating a reading error

Thank you for any clues you can give me. I hope I didn't put too much detail into this question.

Laurel

.....

```
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 2769]
Running…
The class count is 1
The class count is 2

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.
```

.....

```
//
//  main.m
//  Using Constructors with Inheritance
//Quick Start Objective C page 137
//

#include <stdio.h>

#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TheClass : NSObject

// FOLLOWUP QUESTION - IN last version of contructors we did ivars like this
//{
//  int number;
//}

// Here no curly braces. I THINK because here we are using 'static' and/or maybe cuz keyword?
//   or because in original we had methods and here we are just using inheirted methods

//  And static is more long-lasting retention 'wise than the other method
//             * * * 

// Reminder on use of 'static' (Bjarne Stroustup p 145)
// use a static variable as a memory, 
//     instead of a global variable that 'might be accessed and corrupted by other functions'

static int count;

// remember that the + is a 'class method' that I can execute 
//         using just the class name, no object required (p 84. Quick Start, Holzner)

// So defining a class method 'getCount'

+(int) getCount;


@end

@implementation TheClass

-(TheClass*) init
{
    self = [super init];
    count++;
    return self;
}

+(int) getCount
{ 
    return count;
}

@end


// but since 'count' is static, how can it change it's value? It doeeessss....


int main (void) {
    TheClass *tc1 =  [TheClass new]  ;
    printf("The class count is %i\n", [TheClass getCount]);

    TheClass *tc2 =  [TheClass new]  ;
    printf("The class count is %i\n", [TheClass getCount]);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify **No one in particular**'s answer even further, a variable that is static will remain the same throughout all instances of objects, between method calls, etc.

For instance, declaring the following method:

```
- (int)getNumber {
    static int number = 0;
    return ++number;
}
```

will return 1, 2, 3, 4, etc., across all instances of the given class at any given time. Neat, eh?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I read through these answers once. Went away, came back and read through them again. The second time I felt like I understood the basic answer and

Comment: and I also could relate to some of the ideas like things being private. Here's what I think now

Comment: a) I might want to declare a static variable for reasons having to do with memory management. Every time I call a function (message a method - I should say, yes?) I wouldn't be reinitializing a static variable, but using an existing variable, whose value I could indeed change, because that variable is *not* a constant value.

Comment: b) If I left off the keyword 'static', I would be creating that variable over and over and those variables would exist as a 'local variable on the function's stack' (Michael said that). As opposed to the static variable that exists outside of that functions stack. Which might have some special use that I don't know about yet.

Comment: If you're looking to use static as a memory management solution, you'd be completely on track. The static keyword is used to make global instances (singletons), which are sometimes incredibly useful. It might be of interest to you to look them up. ;)

Comment: c) Also I see that the standard for C is online, and I have the url for that. I downloaded it, of course and looked for the word 'static' in it. It occurs 80 times. I must say, and brand myself by doing so, that it is overwhelming. I looked at the Table of Contents in relationshhip to the 80 occurences and tried to guess how I would have tried to answer this question by looking at the standard.

Comment: d) Also now I'm wondering about the standard for C, versus using Objective-C. I think that C++ is a superset of C. Is that right? And that Objective-C is a variation of C++. Occasionally the author of this book says that Objective-C doesn't support some feature of C++.

Comment: I'm not really expecting to understand the answer to d) right now. I'm putting it out there for myself to come to terms with as I make progress.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry I keep hitting the *return* key without meaning to and creating more comments than I mean to.

Comment: OK, I will add learning about 'global instances' to my ToDo list. I know I saw a passing reference to them today. I think in Stroustrup. And I know I'm not supposed to use him, but at the same time he's the king that started things going. So I can't exactly ignore him.

Comment: Laurel, just try to make sure you keep C++ and Objective-C separate in your mind. C++ and Objective-C are both supersets of C, but neither are related in any way to each other, besides their heritage. Objective-C is translated by the compiler into pure C, C++ is not. The features between both languages are not the same, and you should make sure you know what those differences are. If you're trying to learn Objective-C, don't do it from a C++ book; do it from an Objective-C book.

Comment: And about the C standard: don't bother trying to read it. It is neither concise, nor totally human-readable. You can definitely look things up on Stack Overflow and Google better than you'll find them in the standard.

Comment: Also, not to plug, but if you're pleased with my answer, don't hesitate to up-vote it. ;)

Comment: I just came back to review this explanation, and make sure I was still on track with what 'static' meant. Thanks for your additions, itaiferber, I am working from an Objective-C book (working to complete one book and then return to two other books). I got a used copy of the Stroutrup book simply to use as a reference book.  Also I am signed up for a C++ class next semester, so am looking forward to learning how the languages are related and also just learning more. Plus, it will be great to have a real, live class, fellow students and a teacher. Self-learning expands your mind but it's hard!

Comment: I will try to figure out how to VOTE YOU UP as requested

Answer (score 10):

"static" is not the same thing as C++ "const". Rather it's a statement that a variable be declared only once and is to remain (hence static) in memory. Say you have a function:

```
int getIndex()
{
    static int index = 0;
    ++index;
    return index;
}
```

In this case the "static" tells the compiler to retain the index value in memory. Everytime its accessed it is changed: 1,2,3,... .

Compare this to:

```
int getIndex()
{
    int index = 0;
    ++index;
    return index;
}
```

This will return the same value each time as the index variable is being created each time: 1,1,1,1,1,... .

Comment: Good explanation, although it might help to point out that if it is non-static, then it exists as a local variable on the function's stack (which is specific to each invocation of the function); whereas static variables have a single address that gets shared by all function invocation (and though it is declared in the function, it actually resides outside of the function).

Answer (score 4):

`static` means many things in C / C++ / Objective-C.

Objective-C follows C closely. In C++, `static` means more things than in C / Objective-C. So, don't judge what `static` does in Obj-C by what Bjarne Stroustrup says (who is the inventor of C++).

In C and Objective-C, two main meanings of `static` are

1. For a variable / function in the file level, it makes a variable / function invisible from other translation units (i.e. other source files compiled into the same program.) It doesn't mean its constant.
2. For a variable declared inside a function, it makes a variable not to reside in a stack but in a more persistent location, as explained by no one in particular.

In C++, in addition to this meaning, a `static` member in a class means it belongs to the class, not to an instance. This meaning is completely unrelated to the other meaning; in the olden days, people didn't want to introduce more reserved words in the language, so they just abused the same reserved words in different contexts to mean completely unrelated things. Another notorious example is the usage of the word `virtual`.

In any case, `static` doesn't mean it's constant.

Anyway, in a programming language, a thing means whatever the implementers or the standard committee members decide it to mean. Therefore I find it always helpful to read the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). Just look for the word `static` in that PDF. You'll learn everything about `static` keyword in the programming language C there.

Comment: "by making a member static, functions from other classes cannot access that variable" -- you are confusing "private" and "static". There is no reason (aside from a basic sense of decency which would prohibit one from making a static variable altogether) that a static member could not be made public.